# Can't position Entry with grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

Below Entry and button are not placing themselves according to the grid parameters. What can cause this?

```
class tt(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(tt, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.widget()

    def widget(self):

        self.inputType = Entry(self)
        self.inputType.grid(row = 3, column = 3)




root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("300x300")

app = tt(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i can't see anything obviously wrong with your code, but when you say it won't obey, does it throw an error or is it just not visible? are you 100% sure that you aren't putting another widget in the same place later on? as that would effectively hide the entry

Comment: no error comes out. :/ The button appears to behave strange aswell now.

Comment: can you clarify what happens, what is strange? and what do you see when this code is run?

Comment: the Button places itself in 0,0 position and then pushes the Entry horizontally towards the right so they both line up.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you see is correct. Tkinter is working as designed.

Columns and rows have a width and height of zero unless there is something in them. So even though you put something in column 3, it will appear at the left margin unless there's something in the other columns. Likewise, if there's nothing in rows 0, 1 or 2, something in row 3 will appear at the top of its parent.

Comment: How would I go about absolute positioning within the tkinter root then?

Comment: @PushALU: why do you want absolute positioning? Relative positioning usually results in a much more flexible UI -- easier to write, easier to maintain, behaves better with font and resolution changes, etc. The computer is really good at calculating all that stuff. Why put something in a third column if there's nothing in columns 0, 1 and 2? Though, if you really want absolutely positioning you can use `place` which allows you to specify an exact x/y coordinate.